# $\lvert y-z\rvert<\delta \implies \lvert y-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$ and $\lvert z-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$ continuity problem

Tags: inequality, continuity, absolute-value, uniform-continuity

In Spivak's book there is a theorem proved that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ which starts as follows:

> For $\epsilon>0$ let the function be $\epsilon$-good on $[a,b]$ if
> there is some $\delta>0$ such that for all $y$ and $z$ $\in [a,b]$:
>
> If $\lvert y-z\rvert<\delta$, then $\lvert f(y) - f(z)\rvert<\epsilon$

Consider any particular $\epsilon>0$.

Let $A = \bigl[\space x:a\le x\le b$ and $f$ is $\epsilon$-good on $[a,x]\space\bigr]$

Clearly $a\in A$ and $A$ is bounded above (by b), so the least upper bound $\alpha$ exists.

If $\alpha<b$, then because $f$ is continuous, there is $\delta_0>0$ such that:

$\lvert y-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0 \implies \lvert f(y)-f(\alpha)\rvert<\frac\epsilon2$

Consequently if $\lvert y-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$ and $\lvert z-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$ then $\lvert f(y)-f(z)\rvert<\epsilon$.

> So $f$ is surely $\epsilon$-good on
> $[\alpha-\delta_0,\space\alpha+\delta_0]$

I am unable to reproduce the last conclusion.

By definition, in order for $f$ to be $\epsilon$-good on $[\alpha-\delta_0,\space\alpha+\delta_0]$ for $\epsilon>0$, we must find $\delta>0$ such that for all $y,z\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\space\alpha+\delta_0]$:

If $\lvert y-z\rvert<\delta$, then $\lvert f(y) - f(z)\rvert<\epsilon$

I suspect that in order to do so, we want for some $\delta$: $\lvert y-z\rvert<\delta \implies \lvert y-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$ and $\lvert z-\alpha\rvert<\delta_0$, however I am definitely missing some obvious step that would allow me to reach this conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$, then $|f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\frac\varepsilon2$ and $|f(y)-f(\alpha)|<\frac\varepsilon2$. Therefore,\begin{align}|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\bigl(f(x)-f(\alpha)\bigr)-\bigl(f(y)-f(\alpha)\bigr)\right|\\&\leqslant|f(x)-f(\alpha)|+|f(y)-f(\alpha)\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: This follows in a straightforward manner. However how can one reach the conclusion that if above holds then $\lvert y - z \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(y)-f(z)\rvert < \epsilon$ ?

After all, the definition of $\epsilon$-good clearly states that we want above to hold.

Comment: I proved that for *any* two elements $x$ and $y$ of $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, *in particular*, if $x,y\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ *and* $|x-y|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Could you make this statement even more explicit? Although it is obvious, on what basis we can infer that the assumption about $\vert x-y\rvert<\delta$ won't "mess" with our conclusion?

Comment: That's as if I wrote “every number from the set $S$ is greater than $0$” and you asked me how to deduce that every integer from the set $S$ is greater than $0$. If it happens for every *number*, then it happens for every *integer*. It's the same thing here. If it is *always* true that $x,y\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$, then it is still true that $x,y\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]\text{ and }|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Just to drive things home, does it boil down to the fact that $[(P \implies Q)]\implies [(P \land R)\implies Q]$ is a tautology?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In your answer, by $z$ do you mean $\alpha$? Also, I do not understand how you conclude if $x\in[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$ then $|f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\frac\varepsilon2$ (I used $\alpha$ here instead of $z$). Since $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$, we have $\lvert x - \alpha \rvert < \delta_0 \implies \lvert f(x)-f(\alpha)\rvert < \frac\varepsilon2$. So for $x\in(\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0)$, then $\lvert f(x)-f(\alpha)\rvert < \frac\varepsilon2$. How can you make any implications for $x$ in the *closed interval* $[\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0]$?

Comment: @schn Yes, it should have been $\alpha$ instead of $z$. I've edited my answer. Thank you. Concerning your other remark, yes, you are right here too, but it is not a big deal. If$$x\in(\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0)\implies|f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\frac\varepsilon2,$$then simply take $\delta_1\in(0,\delta_0)$, and then$$x\in[\alpha-\delta_1,\alpha+\delta_1]\implies x\in(\alpha-\delta_0,\alpha+\delta_0)\implies|f(x)-f(\alpha)|<\frac\varepsilon2.$$